# How to catch Javascript TypeError?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

```
<div class="member_management_area" style="display:none">
    <div class="member_search">
        <a class="member_search_zone">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger searchMenuyo" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span name="searchMenu" id="searchMenu">검색 유형을 선택하세요</span>
        </a>
        <input type="text" name="keyword">
            <a class="memberSearch_bt">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <select id="choiceSearchMenu" name="type" onchange="menuDisplay(this.form)">
                <option value="0"> ---- 선택하세요 ---- </option>
                <option value="1">아이디로 검색</option>
                <option value="2">끝 번호로 검색</option>     
            </select>
    </div>
</div>

$('.searchMenuyo').click(function()
{
    $('#choiceSearchMenu').slideDown(); 
});

$('#choiceSearchMenu').mouseout(function()
{
    $('#choiceSearchMenu').slideUp();
});

function menuDisplay(frm)
{
    var menu = frm.type.selectedIndex;
    console.log(menu);

    if(menu == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById('searchMenu').innerHTML('Search ID');
    }

    if(menu == 2)
    {
        document.getElementById('searchMenu').innerHTML('Search Last PhoneNumber');
    }
}
```

[image]

If you select the value of the select option from the slideDown menu, 
the value must be changed, but continue to var menu = frm.type.selectedIndex; 
In this part, Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'type' of null.

Why is this error happening and how can I fix it?

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: It means the variable `frm` is undefined. Meaning, that the function is not getting the form element when the function is called.

Comment: An error occurred because there was no form tag. So I added a form tag and I ran the project, but this time document.getElementById ('searchMenu'). InnerHTML ('Search ID'); In this passage, Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById (...). InnerHTML is not a function. Why does this error occur? @NisargShah

Comment: That's because `innerHTML` is not a function. You can set it like this: `document.getElementById('searchMenu').innerHTML = 'Search ID';`

Comment: oh my god... thank you It is work.. and I have one question. Can you answer the question? @NisargShah

Comment: Sure..You're welcome!

Comment: I posted a question in the morning but nobody answered. The link to the question is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527957/how-to-fix-session-errors-when-logging-in-to-ajax-members-spring-mvc2)Sorry for the trouble, but please check the question.

Comment: No probs, I will check and see if I could help in any way. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Leave a comment if you have any questions or problems. @NisargShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'type' of null" means that the `frm` variable is undefined. Meaning, it isn't getting its value when the function is called during `onchange` event.

```
var menu = frm.type.selectedIndex;
```

Also, regarding your query about `innerHTML`, you could set its value like this:

```
document.getElementById('searchMenu').innerHTML = 'Search ID';
```